# Conditional Join Two Tables to update a column

Tags: sql

I have an issues with a sql query and am unable to figure out a solution for it.

I am joining multiple tables, two of them are

```
table_a
----------
id  name 
1   John    
2   Constantine
3   Ceasar 
4   Romeo

table_d
----------
id
2
```

I want to join these two tables and have the output as

```
id  name 
1   John    
2   NULL
3   Ceasar 
4   Romeo
```

i.e. if the id exists in `table_d` then delete the name from output.
Example SQL

```
SELECT 
    id,
    IF d.id EXISTS THEN NULL
    ELSE name
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b ...
JOIN table_c ...
JOIN table_d d ON a.id = d.id
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (`IF` isn't standard SQL.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` and then check whether the `id` from table `d` is `NULL`. If it is, show the `name` from table `a`.

```
SELECT a.id, IF(d.id IS NULL, a.name, NULL) AS name
FROM table_a AS a
LEFT JOIN table_d AS d ON a.id = d.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT table_a.id,case when D.id is not null then null else
 table_a.name end as name 

FROM
(VALUES('1','John'),('2','Constantine'),('3','Ceasar'),('4','Romeo'))
 AS table_a(id,name) 

LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT *  FROM (VALUES('2')) AS table_d(id) )D ON
 table_a.id = D.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I offer my solution using the exists operator in SQL

```
select a.id, 
case when exists
(select * from table_d 
where id=a.id) then null else a.name end as name 
from table_a a
```

Hope it helps.